# Looking for some good video players

Tags: video

I'm looking for some good php video players to choose from. I know JWPlayer and Flowplayer are really nice, but i think there should be more choice than this. The only criterium is that it has to be compatible with php. A little extra thing is it would be nice if it would not show a watermark of the player. this is not the most important thing tho.

Any suggestions are greatly appriciated.

**Edit** I'm sorry I know php is a server-sided language, my question is really: I want to find good video players to use on my php powered website.

Comment: PHP can't play video.

Comment: Client-side video playback has absolutely nothing to do with server-side PHP, there's no compatibility to worry about.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. All it does is process some code, and then generates (usually) an HTML response which is sent back to the client. You can generate the code necessary to display a video player in PHP, but the player itself is generally written in Flash, and sometimes controlled with JavaScript. Both those players you've cited are good, what problems are you having with them? If you don't want a watermark, you're going to have to fork over some money. People put a lot of work into those, why should they give it away for free?

Comment: The player will be client side, so PHP is irrelevant. However, to answer your question JWPlayer is best in my opinion for free players because the watermark that you and everyone else on the planet seems to have a problem with is only visible for about 10 seconds, then disappears. Not too much to ask considering all the work they did for a fantastically stable video player that works on all platforms, including the flash hating mac OS's.

Comment: You can always purchase a JWPlayer license. It's not as if it's hugely pricey.

Comment: Just edit out the PHP part and ask for good (Flash) video players. Better yet, search around, because I'm sure you'll find a lot of these types of question already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at mediaelement.js

Comment: Oh this is a very nice media player! thanks tommy!